# Using ejs input for js if statement

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, ejs

I have a code problem I need to do for a class. I have a database that has users, another table has the titles which the user has access to. I'm trying to make a page where they can edit a user and when they click the button the form fills automatically with the id, first name and last name fine.

Now I'm trying to show what access the user selected has access to at the moment. And what I thought would just be a simple if statement has turned into a headache, it seems I can't access the id variable inside the html code that I want to insert and when I try to put the if statement outside, it says errors with the http headers, like it is sending too many renders. How can I accomplish this?

So here the code works but it loads the tabs of all of the users but I would like to filter the results based on the id.

```
<tbody>
 <% all_users_to_modify.forEach(function(row){ %>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-b-0"
     onClick="fillForm('<%= row.id %>','<%= row.f_name %>','<%= row.l_name %>');";
     onclick="moneyCalc('<%= row.id %>')" >
     <%= row.id %>
    </button>
   </td>
   <td><%= row.f_name %></td>
   <td><%= row.l_name %></td>
   <td><%= row.email %></td>
   <td><%= row.phone_number %></td>
  </tr>
 <% }); %>
</tbody>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap"> 
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Acceso</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="lastResult">

 </tbody>
</table>

function moneyCalc(id) {
    'use strict';
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;

    if (id) {
        var html_to_insert = `
      <% list_of_all_users_tabs.forEach(function(row1){ %>
       <tr>
        <td><%= row1.tab_name %> </td>
       </tr>
      <% }); %>                                
        `;
     lastResult.innerHTML += html_to_insert;
    }
  }
```

Now this is what I would like to do, in each row of the list_of_all_users_tabs it has a column that is the user_id and the other column is tab_name. So I have had two ideas but neither seem to work.

First idea was to put a while loop to compare the user_id in the db and the input id however I get: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:

```
function moneyCalc(id) {
    'use strict';
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    if (id) {
      while(list_of_all_users_tabs.user_id == id) {
        var html_to_insert = `
        <% list_of_all_users_tabs.forEach(function(row1){ %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= row1.tab_name %> </td>
          </tr>
        <% }); %>                                
        `;
      lastResult.innerHTML += html_to_insert;
      }
    }
  }
```

Second idea had an if statement in the html code however it says id not defined:

```
function moneyCalc(id) {
    'use strict';
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;

    if (id) {
        var html_to_insert = `
      <% list_of_all_users_tabs.forEach(function(row1){ %>
        <% if(row1.id == id) { %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= row1.tab_name %> </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
      <% }); %>                                
        `;
      lastResult.innerHTML += html_to_insert;
      }
  }
```

Comment: First thing, wrap your function inside <script/> tag

Comment: Yea figured I'd only include the code necessary, its all wrapped in script at the bottom of the ejs file.

Comment: I posted an answer, it will be helpful other too, so accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your javascript code into `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
//Your code goes here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you header status to 200 in your route file.

```
res.json({
            success: 'updated',
            status: 200
        })
```

And write you JS code inside `<script>  </script>` tags only.